# Clarify "Insertion-sort if the priority-queue implemented with an ordered array", why 'ordered" required?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, priority-queue, insertion-sort

Insertion-sort works also on unordered array, like the example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases) shows. This statement in the title (or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms)) for some odd reason requires that you have an ordered array to implement priority-queue for the insertion sort, why does it have such requirement? What does this Wikipedia -thing [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms) actually mean (the below screenshot)?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article relates the usage of priority queue for sorting and how different implementations of priority queue correspond with familiar sorting algorithms.

Let us consider ADT priority queue with operation `pop()` which takes out the "smallest" element as defined by a comparison function and `push()` which put a new element in the priority queue. Then sorting can be done by calling `push()` to push all elements in the unsorted array into the priority queue and calling `pop()` until the priority queue is empty and put the popped out element into an array (well, you can define a method `empty()` to check whether the ADT is empty).

Psuedocode:

```
unsorted[]
sorted[]
priority_queue q

foreach element in unsorted
    q.push(element)

i = 0
while !q.empty()
    sorted[i] = q.pop()
    i = i + 1
```

Then we talk about how to implement the priority queue. Typically, it is efficiently implemented with heap. However, it is not necessary to be heap - you can implement it in less efficient ways, which is with unordered array or ordered array as mentioned in Wikipedia article. As long as the implementation satisfy the requirement for the `push()` and `pop()` operations then it is fine.

For unordered array, you can `push()` by placing the element directly just after the last element - since it is *unordered*. When you `pop()`, since the array is unordered, you need to search through the whole array and pick out the largest element. (Removal can be done easily, by swapping the last element in the unordered array to the position of the element being popped out). It is similar to selection sort, since you are essentially go through the list of unsorted elements (which is in the priority queue) and pick out the largest element to put into sorted portion.

You can see that insertion operation in insertion sort is being done in the `push()` operation here.

For ordered array, you can `pop()` by just taking out the first element (removal can be done easily by maintaining a starting index). But `push()` will require you to find out where to place the element to maintain the order (since it is an *ordered* array). This is the part where it closely resembles insertion sort, since you are trying to insert the current element to the sorted portion (the priority queue implemented as ordered array).

You can see that selection operation in selection sort is being done in the `pop()` operation here.

Comment: ...freaking cool +1! I did not understand the sorting can be done so easily with Priority Queue, thank you :D Is there any easy way to test it in practise in some programming language let say Python? I am trying to understand this by doing...

Comment: @hhh: Check this out: http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html , it is implementation of priority queue with heap. You need to write your own implementation for priority with unordered/ordered array, but it should be easy enough. The point of priority queue is that it will pop out the "smallest" element, so we can use that properly for sorting.

Comment: I cannot understand: `"But push() will require you to find out where to place the element to maintain the order (since it is an ordered array)"`. This `"(since it is an ordered array)"`? Cannot see the dif between the unordered array and ordered array here. Suppose I give some decimal priority to every element in `push()` and axioms such as `min(insert(v,new()))=v`, more [here](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/priorityque.html). Now in pop, I just select the smallest element because priorities in real numbers dense. What does it matter whether I have ordered or unordered?

Comment: @hhh: It is the implementation of the priority queue, **not the array you are trying to sort**. Since you want the priority queue array to be ordered, when you push, you need to try to insert it in the array, rather than placing it after the last element. You need to get the confusion of implementation versus the array to be sorted out of your head first. (And the axiom there is for empty array, there is another axiom for insertion to non-empty array).

Comment: If you're implementing PQ with ordered array, you keep array ordered, so when you doing `push()` you're finding place for new element. But when you're doing `pop()` you just getting first element. It works other way around when you're unordered array - you just adding an element when you `push()`, but you scanning all elements when you need to do `pop()`

Comment: @nhahtdh where can you find more info about the axiomization? I feel very confused. I have Cormen but it does not cover this or I cannot find anything relevant, still feeling puzzled.

Comment: @RomanPekar Thank you, I think I understood it: if you implement insertion sort with unordered array with PQ, the "cache"/middle-storage is unordered so pop must handle the ordering. If the implementation with ordered array with PQ, the cache/middle-storage with push does the ordering so no need for the ordering in the pop. Is this reciting correct?

Comment: @hhh: Your understanding is basically correct. (About axiomization, clause 2 says that the smallest element (in a queue where you insert the first element) is the first element, clause 4 says that if the new element is smaller than the smallest element in the current queue, then it is the smallest element in the new queue, otherwise, the smallest element in the new queue is the same as the smallest element in the old queue).

Comment: **Summarum:** Back to the title, so insertion-sort could be implemented with PQ and unordered array? The article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Equivalence_of_priority_queues_and_sorting_algorithms) had only examples about traditional implementation and they could be done in other ways like here with unordered array, PQ and insertion-sort? I am trying to understand what value the priority queue in each algorithm actually have, is there some algorithm where priority-queue is very essential? Why does Wikipedia mention the algos? Is there better examples for PQ usage?

Comment: @hhh: The usage of priority queue implemented by **ordered array** for sorting is *equivalent* but not exactly the same as the insertion sort algorithm (one uses a data structure, the other operates directly on the array). As for algorithm that uses PQ, Dijkstra algorithm is one prominent one.